# Is it a good practice to store a struct in shared memory?

Tags: c, shared-memory

I've been searching and I didn't found anything valuable, so I'm asking here.

Is it a good practice to save structs directly in the shared memory in C? I mean, something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    ...
} foo;

int id = shmget(sizeof(foo), ...);
foo* bar = (foo*) shmat(id, ...);
```

Or is it better to allocate an array and storing there only the fields you need, for example

```
#define SHM_FIELD_A(shm) (*(shm))
#define SHM_FIELD_B(shm) (*(shm) + 1)
```

If I wanted to store a complex struct (with doubles, chars, different size data) it would probably be better to use a struct. But, if I only want to store integers, which would be better?

Comment: generally speaking it all depends on your requirements.

Comment: how would you store it if you passed all that data to another function? chances are, you want to store it in shm a similar way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please don't cast the return value of `shmat()` in C, there's no point in doing so and it can hide errors.

Second, you never say what you mean by "good" and "better"; what are you optimizing for?

I would certainly recommend storing structures if that make sense to the application, if the values are related enough to warrant storing them in a structure, then sharing that structure should make just as much sense.

Of course this implies that the applications sharing this access are so tighly coupled that having to share a struct declaration is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

By storing the structure you will delegate all the boring work (field access, allocation size, alignment) to the compiler. I see no danger in having it as a structure. Structure or array - it is still a chunk of memory. Structure layout tells compiler what offsets to generate, when you want to access something inside by meaningful name.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of shared memory is the Inter-process communication (IPC). If it is not the goal I don't find any reason in saving in shared memory